# Why is phase rotation needed to produce the colored inversion operator?

Tags: geophysics, inversion

In seismic analysis, why is a –90 degree phase rotation required on the amplitude spectrum to produce the colored inversion operator?

Comment: Welcome to Earth Science Stack Exchange! You might need to add some details to your question, for example, what have you read about coloured inversion?

Comment: In coloured inversion there is a single operator, O, which is applied to the seismic trace Sto transform it directly into the inversion result Z: Z=O*S. Where operator O is in frequency domain.So we produce the amplitude spectrum,Z and the average seismic spectrum, S in order to obtain Operator,O. Thenafter finding Z/S, and shifting the phase of operator by -90deg. will produce the coloured inversion operator. Somebody please explain why the phase shift/rotation of -90deg is necessary asap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When performing "imaging" we are generally attempting to recover the reflectivity of the earth.  At zero offset the reflectivity is the *difference* in Acoustic Impedance (AI) normalized by the sum. When performing colored inversion we are seeking to recover a layered representation of the band limited AI and not the reflectivity.  As we go from an AI log to a reflectivity log by differentiating we need to integrate to go the other way.  In the frequency domain integration is a -90 degree phase term and an amplitude weight term.  The amplitude term (1/freq) is taken care of when matching the spectra to that of the well log in the amplitude term.

Comment: can u pls explain the line below 
" In the frequency domain integration is a -90 degree phase term and an amplitude weight term"
u can send any external weblink also if need
again tq sir

Comment: The normal incidence reflectivity function can be approximated by applying a differentiator operator to the one-half natural logarithm of acoustic impedance (Peterson et al, 1955, http://library.seg.org/doi/pdf/10.1190/1.1438155). As such, to recover the acoustic impedance function from reflectivity, we must apply an integrator operator. This operator is a low-pass filter with a -90 degree phase rotation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passive_integrator_circuit).